# Ruby on Rails how to print join tables from view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a cases manage system in Ruby on Rails. I have two tables: audit_cases and ra_cases. 'audit_cases' has the columns 'Audit_Charge_Code' (primary key) and 'Client_ID'. 'ra_cases' has the columns 'audit_case_id'(foreign key), 'RA_Charge_Code','RA_Manager','RA_IC','RA_Performer' etc.

I have already join the two tables

model:

```
    class RaCase < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :audit_case 
    end

    class AuditCase < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.primary_key = "Audit_Charge_Code"
        has_many :ra_cases 
    end
```

controller:

```
    def index
            @a_cases = AuditCase.includes(:ra_cases).all
    end
```

view:

```
    <% @a_cases.each do |a_case| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= a_case.Client_ID %></td>
            <td><%= a_case.Audit_Charge_Code %></td>
            <td><%= a_case.ra_cases.each do |ra_case| %>
              <%= ra_case.RA_Charge_Code %> <%= ra_case.RA_Performer %><br>
              <% end %>
            </td>
          </tr>
    <% end %>
```

I expect the output will be:

```
    ClientID    AuditChargeCode RAChargeCode
    PCC502  PCC5020218  PCC5027119
    PCC502  PCC5020218  PCC5027120
    PCC502  PCC5020218  PCC5027121
```

But the actual output is:

```
    ClientID    AuditChargeCode RAChargeCode
    PCC502  PCC5020218  PCC5027119
                        PCC5027120
                        PCC5027121
                        [#<RaCase id: 1, audit_case_id: "PCC5020218", RA_Charge_Code: "PCC5027119", RA_Manager: "7829", RA_IC: "7687", RA_Performer: "7572", case_type: "GITC", fee: 75000, created_at: "2019-03-21 13:57:03", updated_at: "2019-03-21 13:58:19">, #<RaCase id: 2, audit_case_id: "PCC5020218", RA_Charge_Code: "PCC5027119", RA_Manager: "7829", RA_IC: "7687", RA_Performer: "7572", case_type: "AP Control", fee: 35000, created_at: "2019-03-21 19:01:07", updated_at: "2019-03-21 19:45:08">, #<RaCase id: 3, audit_case_id: "PCC5020218", RA_Charge_Code: "PCC5027119", RA_Manager: "7829", RA_IC: "7687", RA_Performer: "7408", case_type: "GITC", fee: 75000, created_at: "2019-03-21 19:14:41", updated_at: "2019-03-21 19:45:47">]
```

I was wondering how could I NOT to print the whole data array [#<...>] as a result.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Here: `<%= a_case.ra_cases.each do |ra_case| %>`, change `<%=` to `<%` without "="

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are printing the entire data array is because you are using the `<%= %>` format. This format prints its results. You will need to use the `<% %>` format, which doesn't print its results:

```
<% ra_case.RA_Charge_Code %> <%= ra_case.RA_Performer %>
```